# LEFT JOIN only the first occurrence of an entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I make sure that if there are more than 1 matching entries in the joined table that it will match only once on the first possible entry.

I try to join a table of unique card payments to a table of invoices on `"transactionDate"` AND `"transactionAmount"`

It works if do `creditcard_table LEFT JOIN invoice_table`
, however I want every invoice joined with matching credit card payments so basically `creditcard_table RIGHT JOIN invoice_table`. The problem is per day there are often more than 1 invoice with the exact same amount.

I ended up creating a view with `creditcard_table RIGHT JOIN invoice_table` with every unique invoices but multiple entries of the same creditcard payment and than using this view in a second view's join statement with DISTINCT ON (creditcard_payment).

It works great except the ID of the creditcard payment is not matches with the second possible entry in the invoice table except the first.

First view `creditcard_table RIGHT JOIN invoice_table`

```
CREATE VIEW "2016"."2" AS SELECT DISTINCT ON (belege."belegID") belege."belegID",
    belege."rechNum",
    cap."slipNr",
    belege."rechDate",
    cap."transactionDate",
    belege."rechSum",
    cap."transactionAmount"
   FROM ("2016".belege
     LEFT JOIN "2016".cap ON (((belege."rechDate" = cap."transactionDate") 
        AND (belege."rechSum" = cap."transactionAmount"))))
      ORDER BY belege."belegID";
```

Result:

```
belegID | rechNum | slipNr |  rechDate  | transactionDate | rechSum | transactionAmount
---------+---------+--------+------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------
       1 |    2230 |   6196 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-02      |  234.30 |            234.30
       2 |    2231 |        | 2016-01-02 |                 |  148.30 |
       3 |    2232 |   6197 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-02      |   69.90 |             69.90
       4 |    2233 |        | 2016-01-02 |                 |   74.50 |
       5 |    2234 |   6198 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-02      |  106.80 |            106.80
       6 |    2235 |   6199 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-02      |   54.80 |             54.80
       7 |    2236 |   6201 | 2016-01-04 | 2016-01-04      |   41.00 |             41.00
       8 |    2237 |   6201 | 2016-01-04 | 2016-01-04      |   41.00 |             41.00
       9 |    2238 |   6202 | 2016-01-04 | 2016-01-04      |   55.40 |             55.40
```

I than use that view "2" in this query:

```
CREATE VIEW "2016"."3" AS SELECT belege."belegID",
    belege."rechNum",
    belege."rechDate",
    belege."rechSum",
    cap."slipNr",
    cap."transactionDate",
    cap."transactionAmount",
    cap."batchTotal"
   FROM (("2016".belege
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (zwei."slipNr") zwei."belegID",
            zwei."slipNr"
           FROM "2016"."2" zwei
          ORDER BY zwei."slipNr") two ON ((belege."belegID" = two."belegID")))
     LEFT JOIN "2016".cap ON ((cap."slipNr" = two."slipNr")))
  ORDER BY belege."belegID", two."slipNr";
```

Result:

```
 rechNum |  rechDate  | rechSum | slipNr
---------+------------+---------+--------
    2230 | 2016-01-02 |  234.30 |   6196
    2231 | 2016-01-02 |  148.30 |
    2232 | 2016-01-02 |   69.90 |   6197
    2233 | 2016-01-02 |   74.50 |
    2234 | 2016-01-02 |  106.80 |   6198
    2235 | 2016-01-02 |   54.80 |   6199
    2236 | 2016-01-04 |   41.00 |
    2237 | 2016-01-04 |   41.00 |   6201
    2238 | 2016-01-04 |   55.40 |   6202
```

As you can see in the first table on January 4th there are two payments each 41.00 so creditcard payment 6201 was inserted twice. With the second query I try to match the creditcard payment to only one invoice. Why is the record not inserted with `rechNum` 2236 which would be the first matching record. How would you change the queries, if possible combining them to one, to deliver the expected result.

Comment: I must say it: your sql truly is unreadable. Also... do you have a table called "2" in a schema called "2016"? Also: I don't understand what tables/data you have and what you want to extract. Answer to "How can I make ... on the first possible entry?" is: "You don't: you select one row per foreign key from the second table (with `group by` in a subquery) and then join on that" :-)

Comment: The schema is "2016". The first sql statement I posted is a view called "2" which I than use in the second sql I posted. Like I wrote initially: I want to insert a unique entry of the creditcard_payment table here called "2016"."cap" in to the first record of the invoice table matching amount and date of the transaction. Sry that my sql is not beautiful but I guess if it were it might deliver the desired result :)